# Unable to Run application via Terminal but application working fine in XCode

Tags: c++, c, xcode, c++11

I am working on [lilgp](http://garage.cse.msu.edu/software/lil-gp/) which is a c language based tool for Genetic Programming. The problem that i am facing is that I am using XCode for the project and it is working fine and shows correct output via terminal. But when i try to run the same application in `DerivedData` of my project in XCode i get segmentation fault (11)

Then i have checked the console in Utilities for errors which shows error like this

```
    Process:               Theisis [9325]
Path:                  /Users/USER/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Theisis-gszeehddtmnlkqdbicpeffygvkcw/Build/Products/Release/Theisis
Identifier:            Theisis
Version:               0
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        bash [8987]
Responsible:           Terminal [299]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2016-09-11 01:05:25.158 +0500
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.11.6 (15G31)
Report Version:        11
Anonymous UUID:        4063B9C3-F525-D9BD-EF5E-358810571673

Sleep/Wake UUID:       CA5341A7-C252-4C76-B694-7F2DAE196F79

Time Awake Since Boot: 57000 seconds
Time Since Wake:       1600 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes:       KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000068

VM Regions Near 0x68:
--> 
    __TEXT                 0000000100c4e000-0000000100c6a000 [  112K] r-x/rwx SM=COW  /Users/USER/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Theisis-gszeehddtmnlkqdbicpeffygvkcw/Build/Products/Release/Theisis

 Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff93a8b09e flockfile + 4
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff93a8d463 fscanf + 156
2   Theisis                         0x0000000100c57853 app_initialize + 195 (app.m:614)
3   Theisis                         0x0000000100c4f245 main + 453 (main.m:205)
4   libdyld.dylib                   0x00007fff8e0575ad start + 1

Thread 0 crashed with X86 Thread State (64-bit): 
  rax: 0x00007fff5efb1970  rbx: 0x0000000000000000  rcx: 0x00000b0000000000  rdx: 0x0000000100c6aa8c
  rdi: 0x0000000000000000  rsi: 0x0000000100c675d4  rbp: 0x00007fff5efb1860  rsp: 0x00007fff5efb1860
   r8: 0x00000000fffffffc   r9: 0x00007fff740b1c10  r10: 0x00007fff97709e01  r11: 0x00007fff93a8d3c7
  r12: 0x450022575a4d98d4  r13: 0x0000000000000000  r14: 0x0000000100c675d4  r15: 0x0000000000000000
  rip: 0x00007fff93a8b09e  rfl: 0x0000000000010246  cr2: 0x0000000000000068

Logical CPU:     4
Error Code:      0x00000004
Trap Number:     14

VM Region Summary:
ReadOnly portion of Libraries: Total=176.1M resident=0K(0%) swapped_out_or_unallocated=176.1M(100%)
Writable regions: Total=19.6M written=0K(0%) resident=0K(0%) swapped_out=0K(0%) unallocated=19.6M(100%)

                                VIRTUAL   REGION 
REGION TYPE                        SIZE    COUNT (non-coalesced) 
===========                     =======  ======= 
Activity Tracing                  2048K        2 
Kernel Alloc Once                    4K        2 
MALLOC                            9604K       17 
Stack                             64.0M        3 
VM_ALLOCATE                          4K        2 
__DATA                            8300K      141 
__LINKEDIT                        91.4M        4 
__TEXT                            84.7M      146 
__UNICODE                          552K        2 
shared memory                        8K        3 
===========                     =======  ======= 
TOTAL                            260.2M      312
```

However, when i checked app.m:614 it has `if (strcmp(c, "regress_asim") != 0) {`
 where c is a chracter array and this array is working fine from last couple of months and in XCode too. Can anybody tell me what am i missing?

**UPDATE:**

1)  The Resolved Project settings for both Debug and Release are same (except for the binary paths for sure)

2) Code not only works in XCode but is also working in eclipse and creating a working binary.

3) The part of the code that crashes in that the  array `c` is:

Declared as

```
char c[100];
```

Initillized as

```
 strncpy(c, "Equation_Default_data.csv", sizeof(c));
```

The code block where it crashes

```
 if (!startfromcheckpoint) {
        oprintf( OUT_PRG, 50, "not starting from checkpoint file.\n");

        param = get_parameter("app.fitness_cases");
        if (param == NULL)
            fitness_cases = 200;
        else {
            fitness_cases = atoi(param);
            if (fitness_cases < 0)
                error( E_FATAL_ERROR,
                      "invalid value for \"app.fitness_cases\".");
        }
        FILE *in_file = fopen(c, "r");
        fscanf(in_file, "%d", &fitness_cases);
        if (strcmp(c, "regress_asim") != 0) {  //Line 614
            app_y_desired = (double *) MALLOC(fitness_cases * sizeof(double));
            app_fitness_cases[0] = (double *) MALLOC(
                                                     fitness_cases * sizeof(double));
            app_fitness_cases[1] = (double *) MALLOC(
                                                     fitness_cases * sizeof(double));
            app_fitness_cases[2] = (double *) MALLOC(
                                                     fitness_cases * sizeof(double));
            app_fitness_cases[3] = (double *) MALLOC(
                                                     fitness_cases * sizeof(double));

            memset(app_fitness_cases[2], 0, fitness_cases * sizeof(double));
            memset(app_fitness_cases[3], 0, fitness_cases * sizeof(double));
            memset(app_y_desired, 0, fitness_cases * sizeof(double));

        }
        app_fitness_importance = (int *) MALLOC(fitness_cases * sizeof(int));
        //Asim Code
        double x, y;
        for (i = 0; i < fitness_cases; ++i) {
            fscanf(in_file, "%lf", &x);
            fscanf(in_file, "%lf", &y);
            app_fitness_cases[0][i] = x;
            app_fitness_cases[1][i] = y;
            if (strcmp(c, "regress_asim") != 0) {
                app_y_desired[i] = y;
            }
            app_fitness_importance[i] = checkImportance(x);
        }
        fclose(in_file);
        datapointsPerImportance = (int*) MALLOC((max_datapoint_importance+1)*sizeof(int));
        memset(datapointsPerImportance, 0, (max_datapoint_importance+1)*sizeof(int));
        for (i = 0; i < fitness_cases; ++i) {
          // printf("%d : %d\n",i,checkImportance(app_fitness_cases[0][i]));
            datapointsPerImportance[checkImportance(app_fitness_cases[0][i])]=datapointsPerImportance[checkImportance(app_fitness_cases[0][i])]+1;

        }
        for(int i=0;i<=max_datapoint_importance;i++)
        {
            printf("Importance %d =%d\n",i,datapointsPerImportance[i]);
        }
        /*oprintf( OUT_PRG, 50, "%d fitness cases:\n", fitness_cases);
         for (i = 0; i < fitness_cases; ++i) {
         x = (random_double() * 2.0) - 1.0;

         // change this line to modify the goal function.
         y = x * x * x * x + x * x * x + x * x + x;

         app_fitness_cases[0][i] = x;
         app_fitness_cases[1][i] = y;

         // oprintf( OUT_PRG, 50, "    x = %12.5lf, y = %12.5lf\n", x, y);
         }*/
    } else {
        oprintf( OUT_PRG, 50, "started from checkpoint file.\n");
    }
```

Comment: The question probably needs more code from the application around where the error occurs. Depending on the debug and release modes of the builds, it may be some UB somewhere.

Comment: Well The Code runs fine in XCode. all the time. But not from binary. I don't think its a Programming issue

Comment: The same code is even working in eclipse and creates a successful binary.

Comment: There is not enough code shown to give a coherent answer.  As @Niall mentioned there is likely Undefined Behavior in the program. The line in question has a strcmp.  If there is not a null termination in the 'c' array, it will read overflow and perhaps Seg Fault when it transitions between memory pages.  If 'c' is something like char c[10] then put c[sizeof(c)-1] = '\0'; at line 613 and see how it goes.  Starting a program under a debugger, compiling with different flags or just luck can cause memory to shift and a program to succeed even with UB.

Comment: In general, use `strncmp` (which takes a max length) instead of `strcmp` when possible, to avoid accessing outside the buffers if there is no `null` in the strings.

Comment: @SRobertz. Tried but it doesn't work

Comment: @MatthewFisher check the updated Question please

Comment: Did you try my fix?  Also try to printf the 'c' array, it probably has rubbish in it.  I think the answer below by @aganju is likely correct.  It looks like a buffer overrun on the input file name. Are you doing a fscanf for a file name or taking it on the command line?  In particular, for a variable the is declared close to the 'c' array this could be the smash and the root cause.  I note that you do not check the results of the fopen. If the open fails that fscanf at 613 will give undefined results.   Add some debugging printfs, this is not a hard bug to find

Comment: Unlike the terminal, Xcode and Eclipse probably set your working directory such that `Equation_Default_data.csv` is OK to `open()`, but then it doesn't make sense to `strcmp("Equation_Default_data.csv", "regress_asim")` with no code effecting `c[]` in between. I'd suggest using "buf" or something other than "c" so that it is possible to track it without adding `printf("%s",c);`s all over the place... better yet use a local `char*` pointing to buf[] with a name that is useful

Comment: Either way, its probably the `fscanf` that is failing, not the `strcmp`, because you are not checking if your `fopen` actually gives you a working file handle instead of an error before using it in `fscanf`

Comment: Just because the code crashes in this chunk of code doesn't mean that's where the bug is. This bug can be anywhere in the code, that gets executed up to this point.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Without seeing the code, this is like repairing a car in absolute darkness. Try it.

However, I'll give it a try.

In the stack dump, it shows that you are using `fscanf` to read data from a file. Later, `strcmp` crashes.

The obvious idea is that `fscanf` reads more characters than can fit in the char array, which leaves no space for the closing `\0`. `strcmp` (or any other code, doesn't really matter) the runs past the end of the string, until it hits something sensible, and then it crashes.

If this is the reason, making the buffer longer would fix it (temporarily). Set it something huge, like 4096, to verify the approach, and then find the real fix.

If you ask why the same program would work in one place, but not in the other - you are probably reading a different file, so the content of the file has different lengths; or you simple reading the file in a different directory, which has a longer name; any of those can be the reason for the char array overflow.

Second idea: The dump line `VM Regions Near 0x68` shows the memory area where it dumped, and its content looks like a part of a ls result or a path/filename (`/Users/USER/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Theisis-gsze....`), so potentially your variable for that path is too short. Make that one longer too and try.

**Edit:** `c[100]` is too small, the path shown there is *115 chars*. Note that `.\Thesis` will be replaced by `\Users\...` by the OS, which then is longer than 100 chars.
Declare `c[260]` (or even larger) and you will be good.

Comment: I have updated the Question. I tries `strncmp` also that didn't worked. However i have project path for custom working directory and from terminal i am just using ./Theisis from he DerivedData Path

Comment: Well the c array contains file names i specify not from terminal and open using FILE* . And therefore i don't understand how will it get the full path. But still you are right i changed the size to 400 and the segmentation fault was gone.

Answer (score 4):

According to these lines in the debug output:

```
 Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff93a8b09e flockfile + 4
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff93a8d463 fscanf + 156
```

What is causing the crash is the fscanf, not the strcmp.
Check the return values from fopen, it must be NULL in your test case (most probably the file that is being read hasnt been found; when running the program from XCode, the working directory may not be the same as you were expecting).

In your case, this should suffice:

```
FILE *in_file = fopen(c, "r");
if (in_file == NULL) {
    perror( "The following IO error occurred" );
    error( E_FATAL_ERROR, "IO error" );
}
int r = fscanf(in_file, "%d", &fitness_cases);
if (r != 1) {
    perror( "The following IO error occurred" );
    fclose( in_file );
    error( E_FATAL_ERROR, "Read Error" );
}
```

Assuming that your error function jumps out of the function. If not, use some `return`s;

Comment: This almost definitely the issue.  As pointed out above the file path storage is too small.   I suppose I would ask why this is tagged as c++11 when there is not a lick of c++ there.  Seems like a more modern file access strategy might be of use.

Comment: As a side-note, forgot to close the stream on read error. Editing to fix it

Answer (score 3):

You need to check return values in C

```
    FILE *in_file = fopen(c, "r");
    /* insert error checking code here */
    fscanf(in_file, "%d", &fitness_cases);
    /* otherwise it fails here when fscanf tries to read from NULL */
    if (strcmp(c, "regress_asim") != 0) {  //Line 614
```

From the looks at the rest of the posted code, it looks like error checking is an issue (MALLOC?) so the copying of the file path (not posted?) probably has the same issues and overflows the "c" buffer, causing fopen to return NULL and causing fscanf to fail.  CHECK RETURN VALUES... if strncpy returns a string that doesn't have '\0' in c[sizeof(c)-1] - you cannot use it to open a file.